# How to work with a large number of components on the form?

Tags: c#

[Not so long ago I began to learn C #]

C #, elements like ComboBox, have a DataSource property where I can specify a table from the database and the data from this table will be in ComboBox.
But when there are a lot of such ComboBox-s on the form and each of them refers to different tables, problems begin.

When editing data, I have to compare data from the database with ComboBox data, and I do it like this

```
ComboBox.SelectedValue = data // where data is a variable containing data from the database.
```

as I understand it, because of this, each ComboBox makes a request to the database and therefore the form opens for a long time (1-2 seconds)

Actually, how to transfer data from the database to ComboBox for further editing without losing the speed (so that the form opens quickly).

[update]
In the settings is: `ComboBox.DataSource = users, ComboBox.ValueMember = ID` 
the code itself MSSQL(0.0027 sec.): `SELECT users.ID, [other fields] FROM users, [other table] WHERE users.ID = 1` 
code C#: `ComboBox.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(data["ID"]);`

Comment: could you tell how do you compare with DB data?

Comment: In the settings isComboBox.DataSource = users

Comment: In the settings is: `ComboBox.DataSource = users, ComboBox.ValueMember = ID` the code itself MSSQL(0.0027 sec.): `SELECT users.ID, [other fields] FROM users, [other table] WHERE users.ID = 1` code c#: `ComboBox.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(data["ID"]);`

Comment: You can make your query first, save it in a DataView and then open the form with the DataView as parameter in the new form. But I don't know if it is faster.